# FPS Skips due to Power Issues, is there anything I can do on my own to fix it?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, battery

My laptop skips frames. I tried to pin-point the issue and I finally have. My gaming laptop (Asus, 17.3", GTX 960m, 4gb, 12GB, i7-4k, SSD). It used to work at full-speed (All Max SC2 at ~100 fps), Witcher 3, almost all on full, ~40 FPS. Now, the issue is not the frames-how-the-game-runs, they still run really well, but they drop every 3-4 seconds, freezing my screen for ~0.3 sec. They go from 100 to 20 in a second and all the way back up. I pinpointed the issue to the power, my battery never charges up to 100% and sometimes goes down to 97%. It's even worse when my battery is removed, frames drop almost every second. The worst is when my battery is charging, it's literally impossible to play.

Did a RAM test with memtest, tested everything (parked cpus and so on). It just seems that some component is not draining enough power for it to work properly and it has hiccups. **To mention: the laptop gets extremely hot (80C).**

It started happening after I hit a wall with my laptop, it being carried in my backpack.

Is there anything, anything I can do about it on my own? Going to send the laptop to where I bought it, but it's a long process.

//Edit: Temperatures.

In SC2: 
Average CPU: ~85C
Average GPU: ~80C

In League of Legends:
Average CPU: ~82C
Average GPU: ~80C

When alt-tabbing to the browser, they go down ~15-20C.

Comment: Best guess: You dislogged a heat sink.

Comment: @Hennes Is there anything I can do on my own to fix it?

Comment: The problem's nothing to do with power, most likely Hennes is right about heat. You need to measure your component temperatures and post that information.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Will do! Can you keep a tab on the question? Measuring right now.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Hey! Just updated the temps.

Comment: Could you stick in a GPU-Z plot?